# Flutter DropdownButtonFormField selected item didn't showed up

Tags: flutter, dart, dropdown, flutter-widget

I have some problem with my dropdown in flutter.

*Here's the UI with hint :*

[image]

And the when we select item from dropdown, the item selected not showed up or only show half of it.

*Here's the UI after select data from dropdown :*

[image]

The selected item didn't showed up normally like in the attachment above.

*Here's my code :*

```
LayoutBuilder(
    builder: (context, constraints) {
        return Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
                Container(
                    height: 40,
                    width: constraints.maxWidth * 0.55,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                    child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                        isExpanded: true,
                        onChanged: (value) {},
                        items: _dropdownDate.map((value) =>
                        DropdownMenuItem(
                            child: Text(value),
                            value: value,
                            )).toList(),
                        elevation: 4,
                        dropdownColor: Colors.white,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.calendar_month, size: 16),
                            hintText: 'Select Date',
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                    width: 0.8,
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                            )),
                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                    width: 0.8,
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                            )),
                            contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                            fillColor: Colors.white
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                Container(
                    height: 40,
                    width: constraints.maxWidth * 0.40,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                    child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                        isExpanded: true,
                        onChanged: (value) {},
                        items: _dropdownTime.map((value) =>
                        DropdownMenuItem(
                            child: Text(value),
                            value: value,
                            )).toList(),
                        elevation: 4,
                        dropdownColor: Colors.white,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.calendar_month, size: 16),
                            hintText: 'Select Time',
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                    width: 0.8,
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                            )),
                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                    width: 0.8,
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                            )),
                            contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                            fillColor: Colors.white
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ],
        );
    }
),
```

I can't find a way to configure the size of font after selected.
Thank you before

Answer (score 0):

Increment your container height or reduce content padding. it will help you

```
contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Decrease the contentPadding will work. in your case, you can change contentPadding.

```
contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(2), 
fillColor: Colors.white
```

Answer (score 0):

Increase the size of the container and reduces content padding. it will work

```
LayoutBuilder(
    builder: (context, constraints) {
        return Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
                Container(
                    height: 50,
                    width: constraints.maxWidth * 0.55,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                    child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                        isExpanded: true,
                        onChanged: (value) {},
                        items: _dropdownDate.map((value) =>
                        DropdownMenuItem(
                            child: Text(value),
                            value: value,
                            )).toList(),
                        elevation: 4,
                        dropdownColor: Colors.white,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.calendar_month, size: 16),
                            hintText: 'Select Date',
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                    width: 0.8,
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                            )),
                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                    width: 0.8,
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                            )),
                            contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            fillColor: Colors.white
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                Container(
                    height: 50,
                    width: constraints.maxWidth * 0.40,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                    child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                        isExpanded: true,
                        onChanged: (value) {},
                        items: _dropdownTime.map((value) =>
                        DropdownMenuItem(
                            child: Text(value),
                            value: value,
                            )).toList(),
                        elevation: 4,
                        dropdownColor: Colors.white,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.calendar_month, size: 16),
                            hintText: 'Select Time',
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                    width: 0.8,
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                            )),
                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                    width: 0.8,
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                            )),
                            contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            fillColor: Colors.white
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ],
        );
    }
),
```